# Yeoman SharePoint generator installation problem. (unsupported engine)

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, visual-studio-code, version

I followed Microsoft docs for setting the SharePoint framework. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment But when I got to the point where you are supposed to install the generator it gives me this error.

```
>>
PS C:\Users\jakub.yaghob> npm install @microsoft/generator-sharepoint -g

>>
npm WARN notsup Unsupported engine for got@5.7.1: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.0 <7"} 
(current: {"node":"12.13.0","npm":"6.13.0"})

>>
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: got@5.7.1

>>
+ @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.9.1
updated 1 package in 8.851s
```

I have tried older versions of node.js but either they were too old for them to work with the new npm or they were too new to work with the generator. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The current supported LTS version of NodeJS for the SharePoint Framework is both Node.js v8.x and Node.js v10.x. You need install Node.js for v8.x or v10.x.

Download Node.js: https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this issue. I found if Installed version 8.x.x of Node and then ran

```
npm install -g npm@5
```

This would lower the version of npm and allow me to install the generator.

I'm only getting started with Node and npm so have no idea what the impact of doing this is. However, it did work as I was able to run `npm list -g --depth=0` and see the generator had been installed.